# String to Object not working as expected

Tags: jquery

When converting a string to an html object in JQuery, I'm not getting the entire segment and I was wondering if I'm using it properly.

**Here is my code after populating 'data':**

```
    console.log(data);
    console.log("---");
    console.log($(data).html());
```

**Here are the results:**

```
<div style='width:260px; height:128px; text-align:left' id='productTn'><img src='images/rProduct02.jpg' id='productTnImg' class='productTnImg' alt='Selected Product' style='border-style:none' height=128 width=128 /></div><div id='productLI' style='width:281px; min-height:185px'><b>Audi</b></div>
--- 
<img src="images/rProduct02.jpg" id="productTnImg" class="productTnImg" alt="Selected Product" style="border-style:none" height="128" width="128">
```

As you can see, after converting HTML to an object, and then that back to a string again, only the IMG portion is there, the rest is gone. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One prints the actual content of the variable `data` which is the whole string, while `.html()` retrieves the inner HTML of the `div`.

```
console.log(data); // prints the actual content of data
console.log($(data).html()); // prints the inner HTML of data
```

Comment: Doing something different just confused me for a second.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dave: When you wrap `data` into a jQuery object, jQuery will treat the content in this case like any other reference to a DOM element  wrapped in a jQuery object. Hence when calling `.html()` you get the HTML from inside the `div`. Calling `.html()` is the same as using `console.log($(data)[0].innerHTML);` which also just gives you the content of the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

`$(data).html();` refer's to the `innerHtml` of `data`, This will return the `img` in your case.

with this `$(data).html();`  you are not converting your data into `html`, you are just asking jquery to return the `html` inside of your `div`

You asked  - *String to Object not working as expected*

Your `data` variable is already an object

Read more about [**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `.html()` method will refer to the `innerHTML` of the matched element. If you want the `outerHTML` you could try something like this: `console.log($(data).wrap("<div/>").parent().html());` though depending on what exactly you need, perhaps you're better off just referencing `data` itself? Wrapping the `data` node just to be able to select it could introduce other problems (CSS selectors, for instance).